# Android Camera Capture and save

Tags: android, mysql, jdbc

I have created an Android app that captures images using camera/Gallery and display it in ImageView. It's working fine.
However, I want to save that image in MySQL database using JDBC.

I tried converting it into Base64 String and when I try to upload, it returns null in MySQL database table.
The code is as given:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK  && null != data)
    {
        // getting the selected image, setting in imageview and converting it to byte and base 64
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Bitmap originBitmap = null;
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, selectedImage.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        InputStream imageStream;
        try
        {
            imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
            originBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage().toString());
        }
        if (originBitmap != null)
        {
            this.imagebox.setImageBitmap(originBitmap);
            Log.w("Image Setted in", "Done Loading Image");
            try
            {
                Bitmap image = ((BitmapDrawable) imagebox.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, byteArrayOutputStream);
                byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
                encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
                Txt.setText(encodedImage) ;
              // Calling the background process so that application wont slow down
                UploadImage uploadImage = new UploadImage();
              uploadImage.execute("");
                //End Calling the background process so that application wont slow down
                }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.w("OOooooooooo","exception");
            }
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Conversion Done",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        // End getting the selected image, setting in imageview and converting it to byte and base 64
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Error Occured");
    }
}

public class UploadImage extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
{
    String S=Txt.getText().toString();
    String res = "";

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String r)
    {
        // After successful insertion of image
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this , res , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // End After successful insertion of image
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    {
          String msg = "unknown";
        try
        {
           Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
           res="Success";
            String query = "INSERT INTO MYIMAGES (picturedata) values (?)";
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(query);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, S);
            int res = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
             }
    catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    String res = e.toString();
}
return res;
```

Comment: Can you read the code you posted?

Comment: Please, in order to do a correct question, you should read the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section and after that edit this question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

first, try to write better the code you post next time, it's hard to read it.

Second, your problem is this line inside your AsyncTask

```
String S=Txt.getText().toString();
```

Txt variable is null so you are inserting null.

Your asyncTask class should be like this:

```
public class UploadImage extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {
    String res = "";
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String r) {
    // After successful insertion of image
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, res, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    // End After successful insertion of image
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String msg = "unknown";
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
        res = "Success";
        String query = "INSERT INTO MYIMAGES (picturedata) values (?)";
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(query);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, params[0]);
        int res = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        String res = e.toString();
    }
    return res;

}
```

}

And on the Main code call the asyncTask like this:

```
UploadImage uploadImage = new UploadImage(); 
uploadImage.execute(Txt.getText().toString())
```

Like this, you are passing this value to the asyncTask that will work on a different thread from the main thread that works with the UI.

Comment: It worked fine . Is there any other options to save image file in Mysql BLOB column rather than convering to base64 String  with same jdbc .

Comment: @RubinaPraveen MySQL don't have any way of storing images directly, so yes, your only way of doing it is convert the image to base64 string and save it. I prefer other solution, me I use to store the image in my server as a file (maybe using a php webservice) and after that store the URL pointing to this image inside my bbdd. You should consider it!. By the way, if my answer solved your problem, please consider chosing the answer as accepted answer of this question, thanks!

Comment: I have not code stored for this, and this is another question different from the one asked on this post. You can take a look at this tutorial thats shows how to do it: https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-upload-image-using-php-mysql-android-studio/